# NodeJS API does't not delete nor update a data in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update my mongoDB data, so far, the API is able to retrieve data and post a new data to MongoDb, but when i try to update or delete data, I get a success message saying either the data is updated or deleted, but the data still remains the same. It doesn't get updated nor deleted.
What could be the issue?

```
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const router = express.Router();

// importing community schema
const Community = require('../models/communitySchema');

// *Communities Route.


// fetch Communities upon request
router.get('/community', (req, res) => {
  Community.find()
    .then((communities) => {
      console.log(communities);
      res.status(200).send({ communities });
      // res.send({ community });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || 'Something wrong while retrieving Communities.'
      });
    });
});
// Fetch a single Community upon request
router.get('/community/:id', (req, res) => {
  Community.findOne({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
  })
    .then((community) => {
      res.status(200).json(community);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(404).json({
        error
      });
    });
});

// Updating a Community
router.put('/community/:id', (req, res) => {
  const community = new Community({
    _id: req.params.id,
    name: req.body.title,
    population: req.body.population,
    location: req.body.location
  });
  Community.updateOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) }, community)
    .findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) })
    .then(() => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Community updated successfully!',
        community
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error
      });
    });
});

// Deleting A community
router.delete('/community/:id', (req, res) => {
  Community.deleteOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) })
    .findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) })
    .then((community) => {
      console.log(community);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: `${community} Community Deleted`
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error
      });
    });
});

//   Create Community
router.post('/community', (req, res) => {
  // new instance of community to recieve request from client
  const community = new Community({
    name: req.body.name,
    population: req.body.population,
    location: req.body.location
  });
  // save the comunity details to databse
  community
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      console.log(community);
      res.status(200).send({ community });
      // res.send({ community });
    })
    // throw error if community detais is not saved
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || 'Something wrong while adding Community.'
      });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `update`, you don't need to create a new mongoose object and pass it to the update, you just need to pass a normal `javascript object` to the update part in `updateOne` query

also, you don't need to do findOne after that updateOne

if you need to get the document after the update you can use [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) and pass { new: true } as the options to get the document after the update

your update route may be something like that

```
// Updating a Community
router.put('/community/:id', (req, res) => {
    const community = { // normal object
        // _id: req.params.id, // we don't need to update the _id
        name: req.body.title,
        population: req.body.population,
        location: req.body.location
    };

    Community.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) }, // filter part
        { $set: community }, // update part
        { new: true } // options part, new: true means return the document after the update
    )
    .then(updatedCommunity => {
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Community updated successfully!',
            community: updatedCommunity
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.status(400).json({
            error
        });
    });
});
```

---

Regarding the delete, also here you don't need to do `findOne` after `deleteOne`, If the document has been deleted, then `findOne` will not find anything, as the document with `_id = req.params.id` has been already deleted in the prior `deletOne`

it may be something like that

```
// Deleting A community
router.delete('/community/:id', (req, res) => {
    Community.deleteOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) })
    .then(() => {
        // console.log(community);
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Community Deleted'
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.status(400).json({
            error
        });
    });
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks very much, I appreciate. It's updating and deleting now.

Comment: I think the issue was because i called a new Community() instance and tried to create a new community with the same ObjectId(id), whereas I only wished to update a community. Thanks for pointing that out to me.